# php works but shows no content

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I was working on a form and i had to use php to send the data through email. I am really new to coding. I just started working with php. My form works i even receive emails through it but the php page shows up blank. I tried using echo and error reporting but nothing shows up no html code shows up either. Its probably a newbie mistake. My php code:

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['fullName'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$age = $_POST['age'];


$headers = "From: noreply@domainname.com";
$to = 'someone@example.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\ngender: $gender\n\ncountry: $country\n\nage: $age";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;

echo "thank you"
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `return true;`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options right now:

1. Remove the `return true;`
2. Move the `echo "thank you";` before your `return true;`

You can read more about return here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Side-note: you forgot a semi-colon (;) after your echo:

```
echo "thank you";
//--------------^
```

Comment: +1 but semi-colon doesn't matter at the end, some IDE cleanups like JetBrains removes the last semi-colon and the last `?>`

Comment: @Zanderwar: I mentioned the semi-colon in case he moves the echo above the return :)